# Regex - match number within a text that does not start with a certain string

Tags: regex

I've searched through multiple answers on SO now, but most of them consider the beginning of the line as the whole string being looked upon, which doesn't serve my case, I think (at least all the answers I tried didn't work).

So, I want to match all codes within a text that are 7-digit long, start with 1 or 2, and are not prefixed by "TC-" and its lowercase variants.

Came up with the `/(!?TC-){0}(1|2)\d{6}/g` expression, but it doesn't work for not matching the codes that start with "TC-", and I don't know how can I prevent from selecting those. Is  there a way to do that?

I've created an example pattern on Regexr: regexr.com/6p70c.

Comment: It could be like `(?<!TC-)[12]\d{6}\b`

Comment: @bobblebubble Yeah, or maybe consider if it is a duplicate at all. I think the syntax in the pattern is off and there should be no quantifier `{0}` Is that a reason to duplicate the question or should we just help the OP solve his coding issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assert not TC- to the left using negative lookbehind `(?<!` and omit the `{0}` quantifier as that makes it optional:

```
(?<!\bTC-)\b[12]\d{6}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Vkq2J/1)

Comment: That is really good! Thank you, it worked. I've updated my regex as well to reflect it.

Comment: Needs to be `(?<!\bTC-)\b[12]\d{6}\b` otherwise it matches `12345678`